# Selecting Data From Last 3 Visit Dates (Last, Previous, Before) - Query Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, date, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to return GPS coordinates for the last 3 visits to a store. 
Current Visit
Previous Visit
Visit Prior to that.

The challenge is that there are 15,000+ stores, each that would of been visited on different dates (Within a year).

I have only written my query as far as retuning the last two visits (Current & Previous) and already I am facing efficiency problems with the query taking forever to run.

The query I have returns the correct dataset, however the efficiency is lacking greatly as it takes extremely long to run (A number of hours).

```
SELECT 
    MAX(ActionDate)     'VisitDate'
,   Store           'Store'
,   Route           'Route'
,   GPS         'GPS'
FROM 
    sys_data.mod_visit AA
WHERE 
    ActionDate  = (SELECT 
               MAX(ActionDate) FROM sys_data.mod_visit MX
               WHERE 
              ActionDate < (SELECT MAX(ActionDate) FROM sys_data.mod_visit WHERE Store = MX.Store)
               AND MX.Store = AA.Store 
                       GROUP BY 
             Store)
AND ActionDate < CURDATE()
AND YEAR(ActionDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Both the store, and actiondate columns are indexed.

I need to find a way to run this select more efficiently so that I can use the query daily.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  MySQL Server 8.0

Comment: As  I understand, your query returns only the "Previous" visit per store. Don't you need all three (Last, Previous, Before)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action date if is = ( subquery  ) don't need  AND ActionDate < CURDATE()  (alreday use in subquery)

and istead of a where subquery  you could try an inner  join

```
    SELECT 
        MAX(ActionDate)     'VisitDate'
    ,   Store           'Store'
    ,   Route           'Route'
    ,   GPS         'GPS'
    FROM  sys_data.mod_visit AA
    INNER JOIN   (
      SELECT Store, MAX(ActionDate) max_date 
      FROM sys_data.mod_visit 
      WHERE  ActionDate < CURDATE()
      GROUP BY Store
    ) MX on MX.max_date  = AA.ActionDate 
          AND MX.store  = AA.store 
  WHERE YEAR(ActionDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

anyway be sure you have proper composite index on

```
  table  sys_data.mod_visit  columns  (store , ActionDate)
```

Comment: Thanks will give these suggestions a go and see what the results are and provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8 you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to enumerate the rows per `Store` in the order of `ActionDate`. Then you just peek the first three (per store):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ActionDate     'VisitDate'
    ,   Store           'Store'
    ,   Route           'Route'
    ,   GPS         'GPS'
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY ActionDate DESC) rn
    FROM 
        sys_data.mod_visit AA
    WHERE ActionDate < CURDATE()
      AND YEAR(ActionDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
) x
WHERE rn <= 3
```

You should have a composite index on `(Store, ActionDate)`. But it's difficult to say how the optimizer is using indexes for window functions.

Also I would rewrite

```
AND YEAR(ActionDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

to

```
AND ActionDate >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01')
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulSpiegel, your suggestion worked returning 3 rows for each outlet, only issue is that it returns 3 identical rows for each store rather than 3 different visit dates per store. Yes, I require all three, however was building it in stages, and just on the second step it it was already taking ages.

Comment: @LeonClaassen Some sample data would really help. Best would be, if you create a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) - save and repost.